# How can I close a file created with Word.SaveAs2 method?

Tags: vb.net, io, ms-word

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Community, visual basic. I am referencing `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`.

The code below creates a PDF file by converting a simple Word file using the `Doc.SaveAs2` method with the PDF parameter for the format.

My problem is that when I try to delete the PDF file later in the application, it tells me that it is still in use.

It seems like all I should need to do would be to close the file, but I'm not sure how to do that. The code below closes the Word document but not the PDF. I've tried using the `FileClose()` method but it only accepts an integer as a parameter.

I've tried it with no value, a 1 and a 2, but I'm still getting the

> "file in use"

error when I try to delete it.

I'm very new to VB coding and would appreciate any help.

```
    Private Sub CreateTitlePage()

    Dim wdApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    Dim wdPara1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph
    'Dim wdPage1 As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Page

    wdDoc.Application.Visible = False
    wdDoc.PageSetup.VerticalAlignment = WdVerticalAlignment.wdAlignVerticalCenter

    wdPara1 = wdDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    wdPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
    wdPara1.Range.Text = "BINDER DOCUMENT" + vbVerticalTab + vbVerticalTab + "Created on:  " + formattedDate2
    wdPara1.Range.Font.Bold = True
    wdPara1.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter

    ' The following statements save the document and close the Word application
    wdDoc.SaveAs(binderNameDoc)
    wdDoc.Close()
    wdApp.Quit()

    ConvertWordToPDF(tbProject.Text + "\", "Binder" + formattedDate, docLit)

End Sub

    Public Sub ConvertWordToPDF(myPathName As String, myFileName As String, myFileExt As String)

    Dim myWordName As String = myPathName + myFileName + myFileExt
    Dim myPDFName As String = myPathName + myFileName + pdfLit
    Dim word As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
    Dim doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = word.Documents.Open(myWordName)
    Dim doc2 As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument
    doc.Activate()
    doc.SaveAs2(myPDFName, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
    doc.Close()

    ReDim Preserve pdfArray(pdfArray.Length)
    pdfArray(countConversions) = myPDFName
    countConversions = countConversions + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Word is notorious for maintaining file locks, so sometimes your best bet is to search for the files generated in a previous session and delete them at the start of the next session, however...

Since this is not VBA - not running in-process - and not COM it's very important that you properly release the COM resources. If you don't, objects won't be released from memory when you expect and won't be garbage collected.

For every object you instantiate in the COM area, you need to specifically release it. And you should also trigger Garbage Collection to ensure the objects are completely released. Years ago, Andrew Whitechapel wrote a great book on working with Office using .NET and the chapter dealing with this is available on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa679807%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

In a nutshell, you need to set every object you declare explicitly to Nothing, in the reverse order they were instantiated, after you're finished with them. So:

```
wdDoc.Close()
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
'Now garbage collection
```

Beyond that, I note in the code you post that you call an entirely separate instance of the Word.Application in your second procedure ConvertWordToPDF. I'm not sure why you use a second instance, but the same applies here, as well.

Comment: Hi Cindy, I tried using your code above and received a compile time error saying that the "Let" and "Set" assignment operators are no longer supported. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Apologies - I'd been writing VBA code all day and slipped into that without realizing it. In VB.NET leave out "Set" - it's not needed :-)